# Unable to use discord.py and quarry at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, twisted, discord.py, minecraft

I am trying to make a discord bot using `discord.py` that uses the library `quarry` to interact with a minecraft server.

Unfortunately once I start the discord bot using `bot.run()` I can't start the reactor for quarry with `reactor.run()`.

I've looked around including `aiostream` and `asyncio` but I can't find a solution. I also looked into twisted as quarry uses that.

EDIT: Including current code.

```
import asyncio
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor

asyncioreactor.install(asyncio.get_event_loop())

from quarry.net.client import SpawningClientProtocol, ClientFactory
from quarry.net.auth import Profile
from discord.ext import commands

profile = Profile.from_credentials("email", "password")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

async def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.create_task(bot.start("token"))

    client = MinecraftBotFactory(profile)

    client.connect("creative.starlegacy.net", 25565)

class MinecraftBotProtocol(SpawningClientProtocol):
    pass

class MinecraftBotFactory(ClientFactory):
    protocol = MinecraftBotProtocol

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(start())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

`quarry` uses `twisted` and in order to use it with an `asyncio` you will need to setup the `AsyncioReactor` at the start of your application.

```py
import asyncio
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor
asyncioreactor.install(asyncio.get_event_loop())
```

After that, you should only need to execute `bot.start()` since `quarry` relies on the reactor running, and just start the event loop. You cannot `await reactor.run()` because it's not a coroutine, so just get rid of that function.

## Update: Added example and explanation

I had a chance to go over `discord.py` code a bit and found that [`discord.Client._connect()`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L449) is basically "blocking code" if you `await` it, but only if you have another task waits for `bot.start()` to complete with in the same `async def`. In other words, it's an infinite poller loop that never returns anything, therefore cannot proceed past the `await` point. To avoid this you could create a [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task). This example "should" work (I haven't tried it on a live server since I don't have a Minecraft client on hand). It starts a server and then when clients try to connect, they get a message saying the Minecraft server is down and then get booted. When a user tries to connect, a Discord message is also sent to the channel.

```py
import asyncio
from twisted.internet import asyncioreactor

asyncioreactor.install(asyncio.get_event_loop())

import discord
from quarry.net.server import ServerFactory, ServerProtocol
from twisted.internet import endpoints, reactor

async def start():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    minecraft_server = DowntimeFactory()
    minecraft_server_host = "0.0.0.0"
    minecraft_server_port = 25565
    discord_bot_token = "APP_TOKEN"
    discord_channel_id = 0 # CHANNEL ID

    # Start a quarry server
    quarry_server = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(
        reactor,
        port=minecraft_server_port,
        interface=minecraft_server_host,
    )
    try:
        await quarry_server.listen(minecraft_server).asFuture(loop)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        loop.stop()

    # Start Discord poller
    discord_client = discord.Client(loop=loop)
    loop.create_task(discord_client.start(discord_bot_token))

    @discord_client.event
    async def on_ready():
        """
        After the Discord client connects, set the discord_channel attribute in the
        quarry factory so that server can access Discord functionality.
        """
        discord_channel = discord_client.get_channel(discord_channel_id)
        if discord_channel:
            minecraft_server.discord_channel = discord_channel
            await discord_channel.send("hello world")
        else:
            print("[!] channel no found")
            loop.stop()

class DowntimeProtocol(ServerProtocol):
    def packet_login_start(self, buff):
        buff.discard()
        self.close(self.factory.motd)

        # The Discord channel might not have been set up yet
        if self.factory.discord_channel:
            self.factory.loop.create_task(
                self.factory.discord_channel.send(
                    "Someone is trying to access the Minecraft server!"
                )
            )

class DowntimeFactory(ServerFactory):
    motd = "Down for maintenance"
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    discord_channel = None
    protocol = DowntimeProtocol

asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(start())
try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: I made updates to my post. Looks like the issue is that the underlying code for `bot.start()` is basically an infinite loop and blocks the code from running. I added an example code snippit that you can use to make your own code.

Comment: I've updated the question to include my current code, the discord bot starts but the minecraft one never does, no errors are printed to the console.

Comment: Is there more code? From what I can see `MinecraftBotProtocol` doesn't do anything so I'm not sure what you expect. Can you see on the `creative.starlegacy.net` server if the client connects?

Answer (score -1):

`bot.run()` is a blocking call, meaning that it stops the execution of the program until it is done. Try an alternative like `await bot.start()`:

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks

async def start_bot():
    await bot.start('my_token_goes_here')
@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def login_quarry():
    # login to quarry here #
login_quarry.start()


# put any code you need BEFORE this:
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_bot())
```

In python 3.7 and up, there is a simpler alternative:

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks

async def start_bot():
    await bot.start('my_token_goes_here')
@tasks.loop(count=1)
async def login_quarry():
    # login to quarry here #
login_quarry.start()


# put any code you need BEFORE this:
asyncio.run(start_bot())
```

Comment: Did you read the question? Both quarry and discord.py require the use of a .run function, both of which block the code.

Comment: `bot.start()` does not block the code as it is a coroutine, you can run `quarry` as a `discord.ext.tasks` function

Comment: When defining the function for loading quarry i did it like this `async def startMinecraftBot():` but its saying `Expected coroutine function, not 'function'.`

Comment: Ok, I've split `startMinecraftBot()` into 2 functions. So I have 2 functions to run now, startDiscordBot containing bot.start and a new startMinecraftBot containing reactor.run
Unfortunately the minecraft bot starts, but the discord bot never does. I'm going to update the question to have all relevant parts of my code.

Comment: Are you sure `reactor.run` is a coroutine? Try using `@tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)` instead. Also `discord.py` is only compatible with python 3.5.3-3.6.6, so if you are on a newer version, try using the rewrite.